# Take row count using windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to ASP.Net. I have a recent project need to read database using windows service. I need to check the database if record is exist before I write that record to database. I have no idea how to do that. If anyone can provide simple sample code it is great.

```
string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConfig"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection oSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        oSqlConnection.Open();

        string commandText = @"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM csvs WHERE Agency='BBB'";

        using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, oSqlConnection))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: this is not related to web services, ASP.Net or windows services. If anything, this is connected to ADO.Net/OleDb.

Comment: I'm try to do this task using windows service. I have manage to insert and read the table to data table but I'm unable to check record is exist or not. I used ASP.Net and windows service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is almost there. You just need the part that actually reads the result from your SQL Query. `ExecuteNonQuery` just executes the query but doesn't return a result (it does return the number of affected rows for `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE`, but a simple select doesn't affect any rows).

this code executes the query and checks if the return value is greater than zero.

```
    bool recordExists = false;
    string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConfig"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection oSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    oSqlConnection.Open();

    string commandText = @"SELECT COUNT (*) FROM csvs WHERE Agency='BBB'";

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, oSqlConnection))
    {
        int recCnt = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
        if (recCnt > 0)
             recordExists = true;
    }
```

note: `ExecuteScalar()` returns an object of type `System.Object`. The actual type returned depends on the query, in your case some number type depending on the OleDb driver. `Convert.ToInt32()` converts the return value into an `int` which you then can check in your code. `Convert.ToInt32()` is preferred to an explicit cast with `(int)`, because `Convert.ToInt32()` also works on other number types. In this specific case an explicit cast would probably work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Efficient way is to use StoredProcedure. You should learn using StoredProcedures for complex/multi line queries. Since you are new to .net and all those so in your scenario here, your code should look something like this:-

```
string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConfig"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection oSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        oSqlConnection.Open();

var sql= "if not exists(Select count(id) from csvs where Agency=@agency) begin 
insert into csvs(columnA,columnB) values('abcd','efgh') end";


        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, oSqlConnection))
        {
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agency",agency);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: @CodeCaster that was just a suggestion to learn. Without that you cannot explore stuffs. BTW as per you since he is new to ASP.Net then working on .net again isn't worth...

Comment: Stored procedures are overkill for a simple select. The sql statement doesn't work either. It neither creates a stored procedure nor selects a count. Have you pasted the wrong statement perhaps?